# Editing a job in At command

Tags: linux, bash, at, jobs

Trying here to modify a job from `at` command.

Any idea on how to do it?

Already managed to list it, delete, and execute, but can't modify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to fix a typo in the shell language itself, look for your job in directory `/var/spool/cron/atjobs`:

```
# type -p date | at 1430
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 2 at Fri Aug 23 14:30:00 2019
# atq
2       Fri Aug 23 14:30:00 2019 a root
# ls /var/spool/cron/atjobs/
a00002018e67ea*
# cat /var/spool/cron/atjobs/a00002018e67ea
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=0 gid=0
# mail root 0
umask 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s\ %s; export LESSCLOSE
LANG=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG
LESS=-X; export LESS
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi; export EDITOR
USER=root; export USER
PAGER=/usr/bin/less; export PAGER
PWD=/root; export PWD
HOME=/root; export HOME
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop; export XDG_DATA_DIRS
MAIL=/var/mail/root; export MAIL
SHLVL=1; export SHLVL
LOGNAME=root; export LOGNAME
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0; export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
PATH=/root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin; export PATH
LESSOPEN=\|\ /usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s; export LESSOPEN
cd /root || {
         echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
         exit 1
}
/bin/date
```

Regarding modifying the date/time the job is to run, that is encoded into the filename for the job.  If we suppose:

```
# ls  -ltr /var/spool/cron/atjobs/
total 12
-rwx------ 1 root daemon 1054 Aug 23 13:58 a00002018e67ea*
-rwx------ 1 root daemon 1054 Aug 23 14:03 a00003018e67eb*
-rwx------ 1 root daemon 1054 Aug 23 14:03 a00004018e67e9*
# atq
2       Fri Aug 23 14:30:00 2019 a root
3       Fri Aug 23 14:31:00 2019 a root
4       Fri Aug 23 14:29:00 2019 a root
```

Then the filename `a00003018e67eb` within the `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` directory is constructed thus:

- `a` is the "queue identifier" (the `a` in the atq listing)
- `00003` is a (hex) representation of the job number, 3
- `018e67eb` is the hex representation of the time the job is to run

The hex value `018e67eb` is 26109931 in decimal.  That appears to be minutes past the epoch since 26109931 * 60 = 1566595860 and 1566595860 seconds past the epoch is Friday, August 23, 2019 2:31:00 PM here in my time zone.

Comment: On other systems the `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` may be different. Consult your local man page for `at` with `man at`. For example, on Citrix Hypervisor (Centos) the directory is `/var/spool/at`.