# How does atd store its job schedule?

Tags: centos, at

On CentOS, scheduled `at` jobs are clearly stored in `/var/spool/at`, one file per job. However, what's not clear is where the start times for the jobs are stored. Job file names are a 14 character hex string (e.g. `a0000101ac6c40`). Is the start time somehow encoded in the file name, or is it stored elsewhere?

ETA: By scheduling two jobs one minute apart, it does appear as if the file name contains the start time, but I haven't been able to figure out how to decode it. Anyone know?

Comment: Did you try to open one of the `at` jobs from the directory?

Comment: Yes. It contains the same thing you get when you run `at -c`. No start time

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537140/233270) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a link posted by Jim L, I now know the answer is as follows:

The hex value in the file name is minutes past the epoch. It's strange that this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but there you go.

Not sure why people downvoted the question, though. I did do a web search before posting, and also tried ChatGPT. Neither brought up the answer.